# In old prototype style "[js] 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation."

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig

I trying to annotate types in my old JavaScript code. I have problems with `this` when using `prototype` class definitions.

For example in:

```
/**
 * @constructor 
 * @param {string} name
 * @type {Animal}
 */
function Animal(name){
    this.name=name;
}

Animal.prototype.show = function show(){
    console.log(this.name);
}

var a = new Animal("bob");
a.show();
```

I get:
[image]

When I use class style I don't have any problems:

```
class AnimalClass{
    /**
     * @param {string} name
     */
    constructor(name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    show(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

var animal = new AnimalClass("bob");
animal.show();
```

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib":["es2017", "es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true, /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true
  }
}
```

## My question is how to annotate type in old style JavaScript.

Comment: Then use the class syntax.

Comment: @JonasW. , I'm not writing new code, I trying to anotate in existing javascript code. And also, I trying to increase my Typescript skils. Thats why I want to understand whats hapens.

Comment: I think it is a bug in typescript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17197 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13308

Comment: If original function was properly written as a class, it usually takes less efforts to rewrite it as ES6 class and results in cleaner code.

Comment: To overcome this specific error you can use "fake this parameter" `function Animal(this: { name: string }, name: string)` or disable _noImplicitThis_ compiler option. But you'll still have a problem with _new_ if you'll turn on _noImplicitAny_

Comment: I supouse that I can't use "fake this parameter" in Javascript code. Or I can? how?

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer This won't be valid JS code anymore. The question implies you're trying to provide types for legacy JS *code* to make it valid TS code with least efforts. If this is not so and you're getting compilation problems from JS *file* (.js extension; the question doesn't say that), then the problem should be addressed in another way. You could just disable type checks for JS files because you currently have them enabled with `checkJS` option, and it's unclear if this was your intention. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files

Comment: @estus, thanks for your help. I trying to have legacy annotated (checkJs:true). I don't trying that the code be valid TS code (only checkable code with checkJs option).

Comment: I see. It appears that you won't be able to type it properly, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13308 link was posted above. I guess you should ignore this file, entirely with `@ts-nocheck` or partially with `// @ts-ignore`

Comment: Kinda sucks. I am new to typescript and wanting to dip a toe in. It would be great if typescript compiler could be used in its `checkJs` mode for plain old javascript. Pretty sure that is what the option is for but seems it doesn't support a fairly common js pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Besides syntactic sugar, ES6 classes inherently provide proper typing in TypeScript, while regular functions should be typed explicitly.

This class

```
function Foo() {};

Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
    this.baz;
};
```

becomes

```
interface Foo {
    bar(): void;
    baz: any;
}

interface FooStatic {
    new(): Foo;
}

const Foo = <FooStatic><Function>function Foo(this: Foo) {};

Foo.prototype.bar = function (this: Foo) {
    this.baz;
};
```

in order to be properly typed.

Same class could be inherently typed as ES6 class:

```
class Foo {
    baz: any;
    bar() {
        this.baz;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm asking how to anotate types in old style Javascript code. Or why is not functioning. But I not asking how to write new pretty javascript code.

Comment: The code above is properly annotated JS code. It's not rewritten. It is functioning but results in type errors on compilation. You should type it in TS in order to compile it.